# How to synchronize a collection in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, collections, task, synchronized

I have a simple hosted service(called `TransactionService`) in a .net core web api app.
I'm having issues with populating a List in the `TransactionService`

In my `TransactionController` I'm using the following method to add a transaction:

```
public IActionResult CreateTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    // validate
    var _transactionS= (TransactionService)_transactionService.Service;
    _transactionS.Add(transaction);
    return Ok();    
}
```

And in my `TransactionService` class:

```
private List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();

public void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    transactions.Add(transaction);
}

protected override Task FilterTransactions()
{
    foreach(var item in transactions)
    {
       //Do some work
    }
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

So when I call `CreateTransaction` in my controller this will call the `AddTransaction` method  in my service class.

The `FilterTransaction` method gets executed every 5 seconds, go through every element of my list and check some conditions, only problem is that my transactions list is empty.

If I add a breakpoint in my `AddTransactionMethod` it will show me the correct count, but a breakpoint on my foreach statement will show count 0.

This is the `Startup` class code to register the service

```
services.AddHostedService<TransactionService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedServiceAccessor<ITransactionService>, HostedServiceAccessor<ITransactionService>>();
```

And the TransactionService setup:

```
public interface IHostedServiceAccessor<out T> where T : IHostedService
{
    T Service { get; }
}
public class HostedServiceAccessor<T> : IHostedServiceAccessor<T> where T : IHostedService
{
    public HostedServiceAccessor(IEnumerable<IHostedService> hostedServices)
    {
        Service = hostedServices.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public T Service { get; }
}


public interface ITransactionService: IHostedService
{
}

internal class TransactionService : TransactionServiceBase, ITransactionService
{

    private List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();

    public TransactionService()
    :base(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000))
    {
    }

public void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    transactions.Add(transaction);
}

protected override Task FilterTransactions()
{
    foreach (var item in transactions)
    {
        //Do some work
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}

The `TransactionServiceBase` class is inheriting form BackgroundService and is a DLL. It has an abstract FilterTransaction method and another one sealed ExecuteAsync()

Comment: How did you register `TransactionService`? If it is registered transient, a new instance will be created each time the service is requested. It sounds like it should be registered as a singleton.

Comment: 1) Do you *really* need to keep global state? That's the only reason you have concurrency issues. 2) If you *do* needit, use one of the concurrent collections instead of `List<>`, eg `ConcurrentQueue` or `ConcurrentStack`.

Comment: Why does `FilterTransactions` return a `Task`? It doesn't seem to be doing anything asynchronous.

Comment: What is the implementation of `_transactionService.Service` ?

Comment: @Andy it is registered as a singleton.

Comment: @Fildor the implementation of _transactionService.Service is the TransactionService class. But it sits on top of another service, but it should not affect anything this the only thing that service does is return this service.

Comment: @Panagiotis I tried using ConcurrentBag but to no avail. As you said the FilterTransactions method does not do anything asynchronous but I can't change it's signature.

Comment: @user3645080 So, it is not lazily instantiated? Or some fancy stuuf? Just plain "return that one single exiting instance"?

Comment: @user3645080 what does `to no avail` mean? What's the problem? The one thing that's certain is that those classes are thread-safe. In any case `ConcurrentBag` is a special purpose connection. Use one of the other ones

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What happens if you do `private static List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();`?

Comment: @Fildor, just tried it with static and it's working. Thanks

Comment: @Panagiotis I tried with both concurrent queue and stack and they behave the same as what I've described above. When the FilterTransaction is executed it will skip the foreach loop because the collection it's showing up as empty.

Comment: @user3645080 tried *what*? You haven't posted your code or explained where `_transactionService` comes from. It could easily be that you're trying to access a *different, empty* list each time. Each `CreateTransaction` was modifying a different list.  That's why Fildor's change worked, it converted `transactions` to a static field. That also means that you'll start getting concurrency errors now as all threads will try to modify the same list without synchronization.

Comment: @user3645080 "It's working" - No, actually not. I just proved a point: There is more than 1 Service instance. So it is _not_ a Singleton. Which has been my suspicion from the start. And I guess the problem _is_ in the way `_transactionService.Service` works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I hope it was obvious that I suggested that only to prove the point of there being more than one `Service` instances around... of course, I wouldn't suggest such a silly thing as solution.

Comment: @Fildor it was, and good job guessing this

Comment: @user3645080 why are you using `HostedServiceAccessor` ? You don't need it to access the background service. If you want your `TransactionService` to be a singleton accessible through `ITransactionService` use `AddSingleton<ITransactionService,TransactionService>()`. `AddHostedService` doesn't specify a lifetime for the service, it registers the type as a background service that understands host commands.

Comment: @Panagiotis this is for an assignment. It was provided like this, and we're not allowed to change it.

Comment: @user3645080 check the [queued service example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) in the docs too. There's a different "writer" that the backgroundservice consumes